# Matlab error: GROUP must be a cell array or matrix of grouping variables with the same length as Y

Tags: matlab, variables, grouping

This is the error I received:

---

```
Error using maineffectsplot (line 99)
GROUP must be a cell array or matrix of grouping variables with the same length as Y.
```

---

This is my code:

```
%% main effect plot

data = [0.9000    1.0000    1.0000;    1.1000    1.1000    1.2000;    1.2000    1.1000    1.1000;    1.4000    1.4000    1.4000;
    1.0000    1.0000    0.9000;    1.1000    1.2000    1.1000;    0.9000    0.8000    0.8000;    0.9000    1.0000    0.9000;
    0.7000    0.8000    0.7000;    1.1000    1.2000    1.2000;    1.1000    1.0000    1.1000;    1.1000    1.1000    0.9000;
    0.8000    0.8000    0.7000;    0.9000    1.1000    1.0000;    0.8000    0.9000    0.8000;    1.1000    1.1000    1.0000];

    data = data';

    g1 = {'(1)', 'A', 'B' ,'C', 'D', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD', 'ABC', 'BCD', 'ABD', 'ACD', 'ABCD'};
maineffectsplot(data, g1)
```

The help maineffectsplot says "Each grouping variable must have the same number of rows as Y"
Y has 16 rows, g1 has 16 rows as well, I don't understand why do I receive this error

I tried different combination of data, g1 ; data, g1' etc none of these work

This picture confirmed that I somehow managed to have them both have 16 rows

[screen capture](http://sphotos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/599793_620559034625330_513091458_n.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You only need one cell in g1, but it has to contain 16 rows. Try using

```
g1 = {['(1)';'A';...;'ABCD']}
```

Comment: I did different combination of data, g1; data', g1, data, g1', data', g1' none of these work, thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to that package (mainefectsplot), I was just giving what seemed like an obvious answer. Looking at the documentation it appears that the cells in "g1" are for different subplots and you only need one cell. So try using **g1 = {['(1)';'A';...;'ABCD']}**. I think that should work but I can't test it here.